# Where do I download the latest ATI Catalyst Mobility for Radeon HD 5470?

Tags: display, amd-catalyst

Whenever I run the update checker it gives me this error:

[image]

[Further search tells me](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130514103156AAMz9Ba) that it is because the laptop has switchable graphics and my best bet would be to download the drivers directly and not rely on the automated checking. So where do I get these>?

Comment: AMD doesn't provide drivers for switchable graphics, but laptop manufacturers do. Don't expect them to be up-to-date, though.

Comment: which laptop do you use? Try the 13.6 Beta driver: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6WINBetaDriver.aspx

Comment: Notice in the dialogue you show: "Please contact your notebook manufacturer for a graphics driver update".

Answer (score 0):

On an ASUS laptop with integrated HD6310 and dedicated 6470M, installing the manufacturer drivers then updating them with AMD drivers keeps them up-to-date and working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Auto Detect Tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) from AMD. It will detect your ATI display adapter model and give you the latest driver for that. If you are unable to use that Find the [latest driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) manually on AMD Website.

Comment: The drivers identified by the Auto Detect Tool or manually selected from AMD's web site are notorious for having problems with OEM hardware.  The only place to get a driver that will work reliably with OEM hardware is from the computer manufacturer.